# Google Cloud Run not scaling up

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have recently built a bit of an automated pipeline using GCP. The main components of the pipeline are:

1. a cloud tasks instance which queues incoming HTTP POST requests
2. a cloud run instance which is triggered by the tasks in the cloud tasks queue.

I have altered a number of parameters in the cloud run instance with a view to auto-scaling upwards when there are lots of jobs in the cloud tasks queue. I have set the max number of cloud run instances to 1000, with concurrency set to 1. As I want to spin up as many cloud run instances as possible when there are lots of tasks in the task queue.

The cloud run instance is based in the us-central-1 region.

The issue i'm encountering is that the number of cloud run instances that get spun up never seems to exceed 3-5. Even when there are 1000's of tasks in the task queue. This means that the tasks in the queue are not being processed within acceptable time frames.

I'm fully aware that i should not expect to spin up 1000 instances every time there are more than 1000 tasks in the task queue. But surely i should be able to expect more than a maximum of 3-5 instances at any one time?

Are there any additional 'hidden' parameters that can be set to ensure that dozens of instances are always spun up when required?

Cheers, SW

Comment: It will be really expensive to have that many instances with concurenncy 1. If your container eg cpu and memory can handle multiple requests like 200, enable concurrency to serve with low latency and cheaper from 1 single instance. This is not a Cloud Function that fires separately for each request, Cloud Run instances can handle multiple requests. And you pay the cpu/memory only once.

Comment: Can you test with a stress test tool the same logic hitting the same container? As the issue could be elsewhere.

Comment: Your question lacks details so we can only guess and speculate. For example, is each instance processing multiple requests? Check the setting for concurrency and review the logs in Cloud Logging: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--concurrency

Comment: Agree with @JohnHanley. If your processing time take 250ms, and Cloud Run can handle 50 concurrent requests on the same instance, with 5 instances you process 1000 requests (or HTTP Cloud Task, it's the same) in 1 second. That is not bad!! Add detail to explain what is not clear/expected from you

Comment: @slw3005 Did you ever resolve this?  I'm running into similar issues.