# Google Cloud Run not scaling up despite large backlog and available instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

I am seeing something similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941775/google-cloud-run-not-scaling-up).  It looked like additional detail was needed to answer that question, so I'm re-asking with my details since those details weren't provided.

I am running a modified version of the Google Cloud Run [image processing tutorial example](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/image-processing).

I am inserting tasks into a task queue using [this create tasks snippet](https://github.com/googleapis/python-tasks/blob/main/samples/snippets/create_http_task.py).  The tasks from the queue get pushed to my cloud run instance.

The problem is it isn't scaling up and making it through my tasks in a timely manner.

My cloud run service configuration:

- I have tried setting a minimum of both 0 and 50 instances
- I have tried a maximum of 100 and 1000 instances
- I have tried `--concurrency`=1 and 2, and 8
- I have tried with `--async` and without `--async`

With `50 instances` pre-allocated even with `concurrency set to 1`, I am typically seeing `~10 active container instances` and `~40 idle container instances`. I have `~30,000 tasks` in the queue and it is getting through `~5 jobs/minute`.

My tasks queue has the default settings.  My containers aren't using a lot of cpu, but they are using a lot of memory.

A process takes about a minute to complete.  I'm only running one process per container instance.  What additional parameters should be set to get higher throughput?

---

Edit - adding additional logs

I enabled the logs for the queue, I'm seeing some errors for some of the jobs.  The errors look like this:

```
{
insertId: "<my_id>"
jsonPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.tasks.logging.v1.TaskActivityLog"
attemptResponseLog: {
attemptDuration: "19.453155s"
dispatchCount: "1"
maxAttempts: 0
responseCount: "0"
retryTime: "2021-10-20T22:45:51.559121Z"
scheduleTime: "2021-10-20T16:42:20.848145Z"
status: "UNAVAILABLE"
targetAddress: "POST <my_url>"
targetType: "HTTP"
}
task: "<my_task>"
}
logName: "<my_log_name>"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-10-20T22:45:52.418715942Z"
resource: {
labels: {
location: "us-central1"
project_id: "<my_project>"
queue_id: "<my-queue>"
target_type: "HTTP"
}
type: "cloud_tasks_queue"
}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2021-10-20T22:45:51.459232147Z"
}
```

I don't see errors in the cloud run logs.

---

Edit - Additional Debug Information

I tried to take the queue out of the equation to determine if it is cloud run or the queue.  Instead I directly used `curl` to post to the url.  Some of the tasks ran successfully, for others I received an error.  In the below logs empty lines are successful:

```
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination


upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination

upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
```

This makes me think cloud run isn't handling all of the incoming requests.

---

Edit - task completion time test

I wanted to test if the time it takes to complete a task causes any issues with CloudRun and the Queue scaling up and keeping up with the tasks.

In place of the task I actually want completed I put a dummy task that just sleeps for n seconds and prints the task details to stdout (which I can read in the cloud run logs).

With n set to `0, 5, 10 seconds` I see the number of instances scale up and it keeps up with the tasks being added to the queue.  With n set to `20 seconds` or more I see that less CloudRun instances are instantiated and items accumulate in the task queue.  I see more errors with the `Unavailable` status in my logs.

According to [this post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/cloud-run-story-serverless-containers):

`Cloud Run offers a longer request timeout duration of up to 60 minutes`

So it seems that long running tasks are expected.  Is this a Google bug or am I missing setting some parameter?

Answer (score 1):

1. I do not think this is a Cloud Run Service problem. I think this is an issue with how you have Tasks setup.
2. The dates in the log entry look odd. Take a look at the **receiveTimestamp** and the **scheduleTime**. The task is scheduled for six hours before the receive time. Do you have a timezone problem?
3. According to the documentation, if the **response_time** is not set then the task was not attempted. It looks like you are scheduling tasks incorrectly and the tasks never run.

Search for the text **The status of a task attempt.** in this link:

[Types for Google Cloud Tasks](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudtasks/latest/tasks_v2beta3/types.html)

Comment: The task creation code I'm using has an `in_seconds` parameter, which defaults to `180`, I set it to `None` and still see the time difference you are mentioning and the issue.  That is the only time component I am using on the tasks end.  Is it possible my Cloud Run image needs its time set correctly or could it be something in the Google Cloud infrastructure?

Comment: Also I had the task in both instances running for several hours, before turning on the logs, this could account for a several hour time difference.

Comment: I do not know the source of your time issue, just that there might be a problem there. The task did not run according to the log message.

Comment: Still seeing the `unavailable`. Here are the timestamps within a few minutes of sending new tasks to the queue, makes me think it is not a time difference:
`attemptDuration: "5.018117s"`, `retryTime: "2021-10-25T16:23:16.719135Z"`, `scheduleTime: "2021-10-25T16:19:00.328353Z"`, `receiveTimestamp: "2021-10-25T16:23:18.207261176Z"`, `timestamp: "2021-10-25T16:23:16.619301336Z"`